# Android change color of lines and switch buttons

Tags: android, css

The question is, how can i change the color blue of all elements in the following screenshots to the green color:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here my Manifest
**Mainfest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/Einstellungen"
            android:theme="@style/_Green">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue color is defined by the colorAccent, you can just add in your file "colors.xml" those lines:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="colorAccent">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="textColorPrimary">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="textColorSecondary">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="icon">YOUR_COLOR</color>
<color name="divider">YOUR_COLOR</color>
```

[More here !](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: that can't be. the colorAccent is in my colors.xml a green color - but you can see that on my screenshots alle is in blue

Comment: is there nobody which change the color of my requested components before ? :(

Comment: Did u set the right theme to your app to have the colorAccent to apply ?

In my style.xml i set up:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this site to create use custom Styles

http://android-holo-colors.com/

It allows you to easily create Android components with your own colours for yourapplication.

Comment: nice one. but which components i have to chose for the date picker, date picker dialog and a normal alert?

for the switch i chose the component "Switch" - that was easy :)

Comment: and what i have to done with, after i put this files into my project? how i set this theme for my switch?

Comment: Change your android:theme in  manifest to android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: i change this, but now my app crash: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: in my manifest: <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="Settings"
            android:theme="@style/_Green">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Edit your question with your Activity and Manifest

Comment: i put the manifest into post 1. the settings.class i will post instead of the manifest, if this can replace. i can't post both codes at the moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98550/discussion-between-sunny-and-ghost108).